# Is it possible that two triangles satisfy these conditions?

Tags: triangles

Are there two triangles with equal angles and a pair of equal sides which are not congruent? If yes, please give an example.

Comment: You're looking at the ASA and AAS rules of the congruency test. http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/prove-triangles-congruent.html

Comment: Do you mean that each of the three angles is the same on both triangles plus there is one side that is equal in both?

Comment: Yes, but the equal angles may not belong to the side. So we cannot apply the rule for congruent triangles.

Answer (score 0):

For congruent triangle to exist, they must both share:
**SSS, SAS, ASA, AAS and HL.** 
There for, on any two triangle with the same angles and a pair of equal sides, the "AAS" rule comes into play, and says, no, you cannot. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is what I think.

Comment: I think you are not right because the angles that belong to the side which is equal in both may not be equal?!

Comment: But you said "two triangles with equal angles", I'm not sure what you're trying to say here.. @chenh.

Comment: I mean that if we have triangles ABC and MNP with angles <M=<A, <N=<B and <P=<C, the equal sides may be for example AB=NP.

Comment: @chenh. Ok, but you assume all 3 angles to be equal. Then how do you say in your first comment that "the angles that belong... may not be equal". Are all 3 angles equal or not?

Comment: I drew both triangles out, still don't see how it's possible? If you do figure it out please enlighten me! @chenh.

Comment: Yes, all three angles are equal. Someone already answered. There are such triangles.

Comment: Can you add a diagram to your answer to help us further understand? @chenh.

Comment: I dont know how to do it. Just take a right triangle and draw the altitude. You have 3 pairs of such triangles.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, anyway, glad you found your answer.. @chenh.

Comment: See this  http://ceemrr.com/Geometry1/RightTriangleAltitudes/paste_image6.gif

Comment: ahh I see, makes more sense now, thanks. @chenh.

Answer (score 0):

Take a right triangle, draw the attitude from the right angle. You then have several pairs of examples.

Comment: Oh, yes - three pairs!!!